Issue: Missing Styles and Improper Font Loading with html2canvas
I am encountering an issue while using html2canvas in my React project. When I try to capture screenshots of a specific page, some styles are missing, and fonts are not rendering properly in the generated image. The output screenshot doesn't match the original page design. For example, in the generated image, I noticed:
Font styles are incorrect compared to the original page (fonts are not properly loaded).
Certain styles, such as specific colors and visual elements, are either missing or improperly rendered.
I have attached a comparison of the original design and the output generated by html2canvas for reference.
[Original Design:]

[html2canvas Result:]

Expected Behavior: The generated image should match the original design with all styles and fonts correctly applied.
Actual Behavior: The image produced by html2canvas lacks certain styles, and fonts are replaced by default ones, not reflecting the actual fonts used in the project.
